# Unlock keyring with fingerprint on login 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, thinkpad, keyrings, fingerprint-reader

I have a ThinkPad with a fingerprint reader installed. In windows I can log in perfectly fine without typing a password. Is there any way to unlock the login keyring from the fingerprint scanner? I already have fingerprint gui installed and it does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need only the fingerprint-gui, you also need the `libbsapi` and the `policykit-1-fingerprint-gui`.

They are all in the same PPA:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui
>   fingerprint-gui

Then it should be fine, you can then call:

`sudo fingerprint-gui` and configure it (you can test PAM service like sudo in the settings)

## Or this alternative method:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
sudo apt-get install fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

[Download the driver](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40v9wedgoau4akh/fprint-vfs5011_0-1_amd64.deb?dl=0:) && Install the fingerprint driver:

```
sudo dpkg -i fprint-vfs5011_0-1_amd64.deb
```

`sudo fingerprint-gui` and configure it (you can test PAM service like sudo in the settings)